# Python-could not access the class method inside other methods

Tags: python, class

I have been creating a python script that basically hides/unhides files and folders in linux environment. Here's the code

```
import os


class unhide_files:
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.parent_dir,self.sub_folders,self.files = list(os.walk(directory))[0]
        os.chdir(directory)

    def general_unhide(self,files):
        try:
            for f in files:
                if "." in f:
                    os.rename(f,f.replace(".","",True))
        except Exception as err:
            print(str(err))

    def unhide_file(self):
        general_unhide(self.files) #unhide_file could not use general_unhide


    def unhide_sub_folders(self):
        general_unhide(self.sub_folders) #unhide_sub_folders could not use general_unhide


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        path = input("Enter the directory's path ")
        unhid = unhide_files(path)

        # testing to see if it works. Directory unhiding is still to 
        be done
        unhid.unhide_file()
        # hiding files behaviour is still to be implemented
```

The problem with the code is that, besides being a class method `general_unhide` cannot be accessed by other methods in the class.

Any particular reason for this? Or is it just a silly mistake?

Comment: Methods on a class are not globals. Use `self.` to reference methods on the same object instead.

Answer (score 0):

This "unusual behaviour" is not at all unusual but exactly how Python always works. You always need to refer to methods and attributes via `self`.

```
def unhide_file(self):
    self.general_unhide(self.files)
```